# Using A4 header and footer on single A3 page

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, fancyhdr, geometry, scrbook

I'm writing a document with the class scrbook. Im trying to find a way to use my current fancyhdr header and footer on a landscape A3 page. I want the header to be in the same a4 format, that I use in the rest of the document. Moreover, I'd like the header and footer to be aligned left.

To visualize what I mean:
 [image: visualization of header and footer]

I have neither found a good way to add an a3 page (I'm using geometry because I need specific page-borders, komaoption and newgeometry didn't work) nor have I found a good way to display my header and footer on a new page. It would be alright if I got the header and footer on the page some other way. The size of the header and footer would need to be correctly fitted for a3 print, tho.

Does anyone have experience with this?

I appreciate any help

Regards

Simon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\ohead{left}
\ihead{right}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\section{some section}
\lipsum[1-3]

\newpage
\pdfpagewidth= 2\paperwidth
\begin{addmargin}[0pt]{-\paperwidth}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{addmargin}
\lipsum[1-3]
\newpage
\pdfpagewidth= \paperwidth
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
    \tableofcontents
\setcounter{chapter}{88}
    \chapter{Chapter 89}
    0123456789
    \section{Section 89}
    \subsection{Subsection}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works a treat! Thanks a lot.